# Using TypeScript enum with mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, enums

I have a schema with an enum:

```
export interface IGameMapModel extends IGameMap, Document {}

export const gameMapSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, index: { unique: true }, required: true },
  type: { type: String, enum: CUtility.enumToArray(GameMode) }
});

export const GameMap: Model<IGameMapModel> = model<IGameMapModel>('GameMap', gameMapSchema);
```

The `GameMap` is an enum.

First problem is already in here: I need to convert the enum to a string array in order to use it with the schema.

Secondly, I wanna use an enum value directly during the schema creation.

```
new GameMap({
  name: 'Test',
  type: GameMode.ASSAULT
});
```

returns `ValidationError: type: '1' is not a valid enum value for path 'type'.`

I am not sure whether this can actually work due to the string array I set in the model enum property.

My idea would be to create some kind of type conversion during the schema creation. Does this work with mongoose or would I have to create some kind of helper for object creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GameMode.ASSAULT` is evaluating as it's numeric value, but `GameMode` is expecting the type to be a string. What are you expecting the string evaluation to be? If you need the string value of the enum, you can access it with `GameMode[GameMode.ASSAULT]`, which would return `ASSAULT` as a string.

For example:

```js
enum TEST {
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2
}

console.log(TEST[TEST.test1]);
//Prints "test1"
```

From the [Mongoose docs on validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), in schema properties with a `type` of `String` that have `enum` validation, the `enum` that mongoose expects in an array of strings.

This means that `CUtility.enumToArray(GameMode)` needs to either return to you an array of the indexes as strings, or an array of the text/string values of the `enum`--whichever you are expecting to store in your DB.

The validation error seems to imply that `1` is not contained within the array that is being produced by `CUtility.enumToArray(GameMode)`, or the validation is seeing `GameMode.ASSAULT` as a number when it is expected a string representation of `1`. You might have to convert the `enum` value you are passing in into a string.

What is the output of `CUtility.enumToArray(GameMode)`? That should help you determine which of the two is your problem.

Comment: My last sentence includes my question, I'd appreciate it if you could read my question and maybe update your answer.

Comment: Again, what are you expecting the "type" parameter to be? Example?

Comment: Due to the schema, it must be a string. And my question is if there is a possible supply the enum and it gets converted by mongoose or some function I create.

Comment: Kinda, yeah. `CUtility.enumToArray(GameMode)` returns `['ASSAULT','MORE']`. Know why the TypeError is returned, but I wonder if there is a way to create an object using `new Test({type: GameMode.ASSAULT})`and mongoose or another helper method turns this into a string so I don't have to use `GameMode[GM.Assault]` each time.

Comment: I think you'll probably just have to create your own helper method, but that's probably not going to save you much code by abstracting it.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just create custom getter/setter:

```
const schema = new Schema ({
    enumProp: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            enum: enumKeys(EnumType),
            get: (enumValue: string) => EnumType[enumValue as keyof typeof EnumType],
            set: (enumValue: EnumType) => EnumType[enumValue],
        },
});
```

EDIT:
Don't forget to explicitly enable the getter

```
schema.set('toJSON', { getters: true }); 
// and/or
schema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
```

This way you can fine-control how exactly you want to represent the prop in the db, backend and frontend (json response).